# What is the plot of the Doctor Who short story "Voice From The Vortex"?

Tags: doctor-who

What is the plot of the *Doctor Who* short story "Voice From The Vortex"? It was published in magazine issue number 364.

Comment: Do you have any specific questions about it? I mean, if you know where it is, why don't you just read it?

Comment: Doesn't seem unclear to me, they're looking for a plot summary.

Answer (score 2):

[TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/StylisticSuck) describes it thusly:

> *"The short story "Voice from the Vortex" by Gareth Roberts in Doctor Who Magazine is a parody of the They Just Didn't Care stories in the sixties and seventies World Distributors Doctor Who annuals, with appalling artwork, a nonsensical plot, and characters called "Dr. Who" and "Rosie Taylor" (who wears a mod dress and beehive).*
>
> *It also features constant glaring inaccuracies, like the time machine being
> called Tardis and having a rectangular console and making a beeping noise when it takes off; and writing the Ninth Doctor (a terse, witty Mancunian) with the same speech patterns as the First Doctor (a fearsome and formal old man), describing him as wearing a cloak and handbag and being chubby, and having him carry a gun and cry for no reason.*
>
> *On top of that the prose is riddled with malapropisms and basically ugly verbal constructions and ends with An Aesop that has nothing to do with anything that happened."*

[image: Voice from the Vortex page 1]

[image: Voice from the Vortex page 2]

Comment: Im sorry, but you didnt answer my question. I want know the plot. How it starts and how it ends. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @John - The complete story is above. You can make your own judgements on the plotline

Comment: "Rose Taylor"? At first I misread that name and as I continued reading was wondering what the heck happened to her that she was talking and acting like that. Mostly, I was wondering what the artist was smoking who drew her like that. Then I reread her name...